# How to connect UITextField to UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have 2 tableViews in one ViewController class.
In first tableView I have UITextField in custom cell with it's own UITableViewCell class.

I show textField in cell inside of `cellForRowAt` but i couldn't connect it like Outlet to VC and use it in ViewDidLoad.

How could I use textField Outlet from cell inside VC?

Comment: The view controller shouldn't talk directly to a text field in a cell.  The cell class should handle the text field and pass relevant information back to your view controller through delegation or a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Not directly Connect outlet of Any Thing Embedded In TableCell

Follow Steps To Perform Code operation with Outlets Connected

**Step 1-** Create a new tableViewCell Class as Below ScreenSHot

[image]

**Step 2-** Now Assign Created Class to TableView cell in Storyboard as Below

[image]

**Step 3-** Time to connect outlets in Cell class created by normally dragging the TF to be Connected in cell class

output will be as Below

[image]

**Step 4-** Required Coding

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell

        cell.fileNameLabel.text = coreClassObject.audioFileName
        cell.durationLabel.text = coreClassObject.audioDuration
        cell.uploadedStatusLabel.text = coreClassObject.audioUploadStatus

        cell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playSoundAtSelectedIndex(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)        
        return cell
    }
```

**Re-Update Answer to Access TF in ViewDidLoad**

**----> my ViewController class**

```
import UIKit

class tableViewVC: UIViewController
{

    let staticArrayy = ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

    @IBOutlet weak var myDemoTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        ///Set Delegates
        myDemoTableView.delegate = self
        myDemoTableView.dataSource = self

        ///Async operation
        ///To make sure cells are loaded
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
            ///Create a Reference TF
            let MyTf : UITextField!

            ///Get Index Path of Which TF is to be Accessed
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

            ///Create A new cell Reference
            let newCell = self.myDemoTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! CustomTableViewCell

            ///Assign Cell TF to our created TF
            MyTf = newCell.cellTF

            ///Perform Changes
            MyTf.text = "Changes text"
        }

    }
}

extension tableViewVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return staticArrayy.count
    }

    //Setting cells data
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = self.myDemoTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.cellTF.placeholder = staticArrayy[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    //Setting height of cells
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {        
        return 60
    }
}
```

**---> My cell class**

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var cellTF: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**----> My StoryBoard**

[image]

**---> Simulator Output**

[image]

Comment: I already do it. How could i use textField from cell in ViewDidLoad my primary ViewController?

Comment: Can you Please Explain Flow of what you actually want to achieve, and what need to be done in didLoad with TF after TableView is loaded,/ I will make sample for that

Comment: Here is what I made for you , Please check Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is bad idea to connect TextField with ViewController.

But if you want to, then first you need to check if you table consists of static cells and desired cell with textfield is among them. Then you can connect textField with viewcontroller's outlet and use it in viewDidLoad

TableView with dynamic cells will reload after viewDidLoad called so you cannot use textfield var in that method

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to link TableViewCell outlets in the ViewController – you should have a separate `MyTableViewCell` class where you link all of the outlets, such as:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
}
```

You reference this table view in the view controller via the function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and there you can handle all actions performed on the cell and by default, the TextField.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    // Customize the cell and the TextField

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Already. I don't know how to use this textField in ViewDidLoad func of primary TableViewController

Comment: @IvanKisin That's the thing though, you're not supposed to use this TextField in the `viewDidLoad` of the TableViewController. Apple has structured the tableView in such a way that you don't customize cells in the `viewDidLoad` of the main ViewController, but rather in the `cellForItemAt` function. Why do you need to implement it in the `viewDidLoad` function?

Answer (score 0):

Put your outlet inside your Cell class, and when you want to access it’s text from vc 
U will do `let cell = tableview.cellforrow(at indexpath) as! YourCellClass`
Then access the textfield easily

```
let text = cell.yourTextField.text
```

But i advice you to remove the tableview and instead use scrollview if its simple viewcontroller

Comment: Whats your question?